# Spring MVC изображения d jsp

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, mvc, jsp

Здравствуйте, делаю веб приложение, дошло до сохранения и отображения фото в jsp. Сохраняется, всё хорошо, но при отображении возникли проблемы, никак не хочет отображать их, даже при абсолютном пути.

Это в jsp
`<img src="<c:url value="/home/max/dataBaseSave/images/${ad.id}.jpg"/>" alt="${ad.id}"/>`

Это сохранение файла, и оно работает правильно
`File file = new File( "/home/max/dataBaseSave/images/" + nameImage + ".jpg");`

так оно работает если находится на странице где нужно "открыт" 28 изображение
`<img src="/home/max/dataBaseSave/images/28.jpg" alt="28"/>`

с изображением всё в порядке [image: вот]

Comment: Фото должны лежать относительно корня вашего приложения на сервере то есть в той же папке где развернутое приложение. А после ребута сервера видит фотки или нет? Конфигурацию спринга покажите, где вы маппинг ресурсов указываете

Comment: а на статической странице отображает? Именно в jsp проблема? Запрос браузер делает? Ошибку какую пишет?

Comment: Зачем вы плодите вопросы? Не отвечая на комментарии?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Вот что в консоле пишет

Comment: Статичная html c этим адресом не показывает картинку, если в idea нажать открыть в браузере, но если просто пройти в эту папку и открыть через проводник в браузере, то картинка будет показываться. Что это за ад то? ( извиняюсь, спал )